# extract common blocks into functions in C++

Tags: c++

There's something I recurently struggle with while working on C++ code.

Let's say I've got a method doing X, Y and then Z. Now I'd like to introduce another method that should do X, Y', Z. If that was plain old C code, I'd then make functions X() and Z() with the common code, declaring them `static` so that the compiler would now they can be inlined if needed, as no code out of this "module" can call them. The method that's part of the API would then look like

```
int M(args) {
   X(foo); // that could e.g. be "check args are valid".
   /* here comes M-specific code */
   Z(bar); // that could e.g. be "update_state"
}

int M2(args) {
   X(foo);
   /* here comes M2-specific code */
   Z(bar);
}
```

Now, if I do the same in C++, X() and Z() no longer have access to the class' protected/private members. Swapping between .h and .cc file to declare those "helper" X() and Z() as I proceed with code writing somehow tempt me to just copy/paste the common code instead, so I tend to duplicate instead the class, having something that's closer to a (java) interface in .h -- with virtually no member variables -- and then have variables, API methods and "helper" methods all within a `class` block in the .cc file, that inherits from the "interface".

Yet, I doubt this is good practice with C++, so I'm curious to know what other people do in that case.

Comment: interesting question. i always found that the class declaration in C++ does not play well with abstraction and information-hiding.

Comment: The class in the header doesn't need to be the class with the implementation in it. You can use an abstract base class or the pImpl idiom to separate the two. Then the implementation can be entirely in the .cc.

Comment: @Alan Strokes: abstract base class or pimpl idiom are cumbersome ways, when i simply want to hide a private member from view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `X` and `Z` are doing stuff relevant to the class, then make them member functions of the class (and if not, then there's no problem, since their implementations can easily be put elsewhere, out of public view).

If they're not supposed to be part of the public interface of the class, make them `private`.

If it bothers you that their function signatures show up in the class definition, then there are several ways to restructure your code, in such a way that implementation details aren't exposed.

A common way eg., is to use the [Pimpl idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm).

Another way, would be to only expose (abstract) interfaces in the public API, and hide the implementing classes from view. This is not always possible, but when it is, it can be very effective.

Comment: an additional "private stuff" class with those private members and functions defined directly in the .cc ... interesting. That class will not have access to e.g. protected members of ApiClass, but I guess I could just use some friend statements to avoid such a division amongst members.

Comment: not sure I love how pimpl forces me to go with data->xxx for every data member, though >_<

Comment: @sylvainulg : it's not very pretty, no. But it achieves the desired effect. As said elsewhere, C++ doesn't really provide a convenient way for hiding implementation details, so whichever technique you use won't be as pretty/convenient as when the functionality would be built into the language.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right what you want to achieve is to write the two functions X() and Z() only once for more than one function M(). Like the other comments suggest make them member functions marked as inline.

Additionally to implementing X() and Z() as member functions I would use the Strategy pattern where you have a function M() like this

```
class ClassTest
{
  private:
    void X();
    void Y();

    Alogrithm* m_algorithm;

  public:
    void M();
    void setAlgorithm( Alogrithm* a ) { m_algorithm = a; }
}

void ClassTest::M()
{
  X();    
  m_algorithm->execute();    
  Z();
}
```

This eliminates the need for a second function M2(). You only need to have a setter for m_algorithm which is a small object which implements your original function Y(). This way the algorithm can even be changed a runtime.

Comment: interesting alternative, but it wouldn't be nice to introduce such a side-effect in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You could move your `X` and `Z` functionalities into private member function of your class and mark them with the `inline` modifier, if you wanted to. This would allow access to private members while making access from outside the class difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong from concepts:

- If `X()` and `Z()` have common code, this is a design improvement. Refactor them.
- If `M1(args)` works ok, why are you changing it? Once you refactored `X()` and `Z()` you can use them in other method. Just create `M2(args)`using new `X()` and `Z()` plus new features in a new `Y()`method.

Comment: I'm afraid you got the question wrong (or I was vague asking it). X() and Z() do not share common code. They are code that existed in M() and that are now needed in both M() and M2(), so I want to promote them as functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the functions into:

1. Make them private members of the class.
2. Or you can put them within an anonymous namespace in the implementatio file.

With option #2 you will not be able to access the private members of the class, while this is a big issue, it can be mitigated by passing in all (and only) the required parameters, and either returning a value or using output parameters (pointers or references).